# with remotely access to gpio pins of raspberry pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I am controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO pins with Android app. Its work fine in my local network but its not working from another network I have created with an Apache2 server in raspberry pi and accessing a .php file to change the status of pins. Status of pins are work fine in my local network and access.log file also show that for e.g led =1 but its is not working in another network, although it accesses my server from the other network but is not changing the status of GPIO pin.

Comment: Wel how do you connect when in other network? `althoght it access my server fr0m other network`. How? And how do you know?

Comment: i have checked my access.log file its snd the udp packetswhen i selects both tcp and udp in  port forwarding and when i select only tcp i dont

Comment: although when i was on another network i give my public ip in browser it will access and access.log shows it but it is not connecting with my android app please help

Comment: You did not tell how the two networks are connected.  What kind of networks? You are not giving any info so how could we ever help you? What has all to do with a public ip? And with two networks you have two public ips?

Comment: i am sorry i am not be able to explain it ... sir i am doing this kind of project in this link ( http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Using-an-App/ )  this is for only when both android phone and raspberry pi is in local network it work fine but when we want to access it remotly by doing port forwarding it not work fine although i test my port 86 it is open and my public ip is also static

Comment: You are not even telling if the Android device uses mobile connection or wifi. You are not even telling which errors or exceptions your android app provokes. You give unsufficient info.

Comment: i am using wifi on android  and raspberry pi is also using the same wifi.when i put my android device on mobile connection then it is not communicating with raspberry pi. and my android app is not provoking any error or exception.

Comment: On mobile connection (or wifi) if your app cannot connect there should be an exception. Maybe you catch the exception but you do not log it or inform the user.